# Javascript to load a range of pages sequentially in an iframe based on time of day?

Tags: javascript

Essentially I have a website that loads schedule information based on the time of day. The way I have it now is very inefficient and complicates things when I need to make changes. I have 7 folders, one for each day of the week, and in those daily folders are 24 HTML pages, one for each hour of the day, then in a folder I have up to 24 more pages with schedule tables. I can't think of or find a script that would cut down the hourly HTML pages to just one page.

Here's an example of the code I have for 7am.

This file is saved as 7.html. At  8am it redirects to index.html which in turn redirects to 8.html based on the time of day.

```
<script>
var intervalId = window.setInterval(checkTime, 500);

function checkTime() {

    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();

    if(h == 08 && m == 00 && s == 0) return window.location='../index.html';
}
</script>
```

This is the iframe that contains the schedule information. As you can see, it loads pages for 7.html, 8.html, 9.html and 10.html from the tables folder (current hour and next three hours). Each table is visible for 10 seconds before the next one loads, then it repeats for the next hour.

```
<p align="center"><iframe id="if_one" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" src="" style="width: 100%;height: 700px;float: middle;margin: 0 auto;"></iframe></p>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pages = [
    'tables/7.html',
    'tables/8.html',
    'tables/9.html',
    'tables/10.html'
], p = pages.length;
while(--p > -1){
    (function(p){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = pages[p];
        pages[p] = a;
    })(p);
}

function loadIframe() {
var page = pages[(p = ++p % pages.length)], bust = 'bustcache=' + new Date().getTime();
page = page.search? page.href + '&' + bust : page.href + '?' + bust;
document.getElementById('if_one').src = page;

  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }

setTimeout(loadIframe, 10000);
}
loadIframe();
</script>
```

What I'd like to do is have all of this one on page. So if it's 8am, it loads pages in the range of 8.html to 11.html. If it's 9am, it loads pages in the range of 9.html to 12.html, etc. The only problem is that sometimes there is not an hourly schedule. So for example, there might be nothing for 12, so the script would have to know to skip tables/12.html if it doesn't exist in the folder.

Basically:

- if 9am, load page range 'tables/9.html' - 'tables/12.html' in iframe, skip missing pages
- if 10am, load page range 'tables/10.html' - 'tables/13.html' in iframe, skip missing pages
- etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you have directory browsing enabled on the folder with your hourly files, you could make a request to "tables/" when the page loads, then parse the output to build a list of available hour files so your script knows which ones to skip.

Comment: It may be easier to just make a config file that the page loads on startup that contains a JSON array of available files.